# I want to navigate to screen and clear all the navigation screens in the stack

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am navigating from splash screen to login/home screen, depending upon whether there is valid token in sharedpreferences or not. But when I want to minimize(or whatever it's called) the app when back button in pressed on home screen. Is there any navigator method which navigates to a screen and clear all the screens in navigation stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, route, (route) => false);
```